# Terminal in Android Studio showing error - Exception in plugin terminal

Tags: java, android-studio, terminal

My terminal on Android studio won't open and I'm getting this error

null

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jediterm.terminal.ui.TabbedTerminalWidget.closeCurrentSession(TabbedTerminalWidget.java:210)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.TerminalView$CloseSession.actionPerformed(TerminalView.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:197)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:156)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:211)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.actionPerformed(ActionButton.java:189)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.performAction(ActionButton.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.processMouseEvent(ActionButton.java:326)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:627)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: `com.jediterm.terminal.ui.TabbedTerminalWidget` tries to access a variable but the variable is null. For real help, we need more details. For example: Is this your class? If yes, please post code, if no, please post url and version

Comment: What class do you  mean?

Comment: The class `TabbedTerminalWidget` as shown in the stack trace which causes the error

Comment: Ok, but where is it located? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue today, and what's odd is it just perform well before.

I don't know why, but I fixed it by reset terminal plugin in Android Studio at settings panel.

[Android Studio settings panel for plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y00ZS.png)

Just disable the terminal plugin and restart, then enable it agagin, after restart, it would work.